# highcharts now showing with activemq's amq

Tags: highcharts, activemq-classic

I am trying to modify the activemq webapp to dynamically visualize data using highcharts. Specially, the following code works fine where chart1.js does the basic highchart line draw. As soon as I uncomment amq.js, the chart stops showing up. It is a known issue?

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- <script src="C:/progress/fuse-message-broker-5.3.0.1/webapps/demo/Highcharts-3.0.6/js/highcharts.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"/>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="chart1.js"></script>     

<!--- <script type="text/javascript" src="../amq/amq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">amq.uri='../amq';</script>   
--->
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: What error do you have in console? For me, this line: `<script type="text/javascript">amq.uri='../amq';</script>` is the reason. Probably this should be done after DOM is loaded.

Comment: there is no error in console. in chart1.js, I already called `$(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });...` so I think DOM is already loaded before the line of amq.js

Comment: Nope, it's not. JS in chart1.js is waiting for DOM being loaded, but nothing else on your site. Anyway, could you show your site with that error? It really useful to see issue 'live'.

Answer (score 0):

The old web console in ActiveMQ is deprecated and being replaced with the new HTML5 based hawtio (http://hawt.io/) - such as in the new ActiveMQ 5.9 release. The old web console is to be removed in a future release of ActiveMQ.

You can build custom plugins for hawtio, or help hack on the project to improve it in areas you like.

hawtio also works with older releases of ActiveMQ such as 5.8 etc.